# JavaScript argument validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am writing an Angular app coming from a PHP background. I wanted to know if there are any good assert/validation libraries I can use to help me validation the arguments passed in to my models e.g. Validate.isNumber(data.id) and automatically throw an appropriate exception on failure

```
app.factory('Something', ['moment', function(moment){

    function Something(data) {

        // validate data has required properties and they are of the expected type!!!

        this.id = data.id;
        this.title = data.title;
        this.description = data.description;
    }

    Something.prototype.getId = function () {
        return this.id;
    };

    Something.prototype.getTitle = function () {
        return this.title;
    };

    Something.prototype.getDescription = function () {
        return this.description;
    };

    return Something;

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use this JSON-Validator tv4:

https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4

It relies on a schema you provide to tell it how your passed arguments(JSON-structure) have to be formed and what kind of types are allowed.

And here you find all validation-options it supports:

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html

Here you find a practical [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274898/json-tv4-object-valid-if-true-and-if-other-object-is-present/28281905#28281905)

Comment: you are welcome, I already used it in one project and it really does what it says.